# Pass :after content attribute with html attribute

Tags: css, html

I have a number of `div`'s, each needing a different content attribute in the `:after` element.
It is not possible for me to style each div individually, because the amount of `div`'s is rather large.

My question: Can I pass the attribute in the html tag itself?
Say I have

```
<a href="#" class="vak">Engels</a>
```

With an `:after` styling like

```
content: "this needs to change";
display: inline-block;
color: #A9B0BB;  
float: right;
font-style:italic;
```

How can I pass on the `this needs to change` string in html? Is there a better way to do this? (preferably without using js)

Comment: You want a variable `content`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an attribute for it:

```
<a title="this will be displayed in the :after">test</a>
```

CSS:

```
a:after {
    content: attr(title);
    display: inline-block;
    color: #A9B0BB;  
    float: right;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Fa4Q/1)

Comment: Works like a charm, didn't know css offered this functionality!

Comment: attr() is not supported in any of the major browsers. I've no idea how this could work for you.

Comment: Hmm.. Things seem to conflict with each other. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-attr seems to say it doesn't work for any browser, however https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr says something different and so does my Fiddle. If you try that, it should work.

Comment: The [Mozilla developer page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr$edit#Browser_compatibility)'s browser compatibility section also says that no browsers currently support this (which is a shame). 

I tested the most recent versions of Chrome & Firefox, but had no success.